# Trying to get to a secure url reverse proxying apache with nginx on dockerized vite application on remote server

Tags: apache, http, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

Ok im going to try my best to detail my situation. Honestly spent a couple days with no success but I think I may not be too far off.

So i have deployed a vite-react app on my remote server, which is reachable and usable with http://[ip]:[port]/[project name] (I had to use a different base url/public url since i want to deploy the application using a subroute of the domain associated with the remote server).

I have other services running on the server. All reachable on https://[domain].com/[project name], which is exactly what i want to do with this new project (I did not set up these previous services).

We've got apache2 running on port 80 and configured with the ssl certificates and all.

On the other hand, the app is a vite react frontend, that has a production build that runs nginx to serve the static files generated on vite build. The nginx server is from a docker image and maps the containers port 80 to the remote machine port 3000, so i can reach it, as I said, from http://[ip]:3000/[project name].

Adding:

```
ProxyPass /project_name http://127.0.0.1:3000/project_name
ProxyPassReverse /project_name http://127.0.0.1:3000/project_name
```

Or

```
ProxyPass /project_name http://127.0.0.1:3000
ProxyPassReverse /project_name http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Does not redirect to https://[domain]/[project_name] as I hoped it would.

My nginx config file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

And it works for a single page application.

Not sure what can i do to achieve my objective, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Everything I tried is on the description. Adding lines to the apache config, modifying the nginx config...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm stupid. Please check if there are any more .conf files in the sites-available folder. It was one of them, not the default conf file.